# The values iterated by .map() do not reflect inside the function in html attribute

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, react-state

In the `Parent` component, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] values are passed and for each value a `Child` component is created. So there are 6 occurrences of the `Child` component. The child component is a ***bootstrap modal*** as below

```
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "../../node_modules/react";

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-white">{props.monthpassed}</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Click to open below Modal
      </button>

      <div class="modal fade text-white" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select project and add an allocation</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <h1 className="text-white">{props.monthpassed}</h1>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>);
}

export default Child;
```

Note that there are two instances where `props.monthpassed` is present. Once above the button and once on the actual modal that will be displayed when that button is clicked.

The `Parent` component is as below.

```
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "../../node_modules/react";
import Child from "./Child";

function Parent(props) {
  return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(xx => <Child monthpassed={xx}></Child>);
}

export default Parent;
```

When the parent component is displayed, it will be displayed like below.

[image: Parent component displayed]

Notice that above each button, the passed `props.monthpassed` is displayed properly based on the values in the array in the `Parent` component. This works perfectly.

But when I click on any of the buttons, the modal displays only one value `0` inside the modal, as opposed to the values in the array as displayed in the parent component.

[image: Child component displayed]

How do I handle this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write return for the map.

```
months.map((month, month_idx) => {
    return (
        <ProjectSelectionModal
            key={month_idx}
            onSelectingProject={(project) => selectProjectHandler(month_idx)}>
        </ProjectSelectionModal>
    );
});
```

Comment: Oops. My bad, there are no braces there, it was a direct return from the map. I have updated the question.

Comment: in that case, you may need to show us what the `selectProjectHandler` function is. because the question is not clear enough.

Comment: I wasn't quite understanding the error properly. I have updated the question with the complete details as I found that the modal is causing the problems, which I have ignored all this while.